# DB access account for SharePoint 2013

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, sharepoint

I am installing SharePoint Server 2013 on Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 with SQL 2012 on a VMware. During the SharePoint Configuration Wizard, I need to provide a DB access account.

The VM is not part of a domain as well.

I tried **VMname\Admin & password** it didn't work. Giving the message that the local admin can't be used.

I need some help regarding this problem please.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new local user on that machine and use that, if your server isn't a member of an Active Directory domain.

Comment: I solved the problem by creating another VM and making that the DC.